# Python and MySQL query with quotes

Tags: python, mysql, string, python-3.x, quotes

With a script in `Python3`, after extracting some strings from a file, they should be used as data to be inserted into a MySQL database as follows:

```
query1 = """INSERT INTO {:s} VALUES ({:s}, {:s}, {:s}, {:s});""".format(table1,"""0""",string1,string2,string3)
cursor1.execute(query1)
```

Some of the strings contain different and unpleasant quotes, like:

```
a "'double quoted'" example string
```

If I define some example strings with triple quotes delimiters

```
string1 = """a "'double quoted'" example string"""
```

the above query is successful. If instead the strings are returned by a function after parsing an external file, the query generates an error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'first string, "\'Quoted part\'" of second string, , Third string\' at line 1')
```

I tried also with:

```
query1 = """INSERT INTO {:s} VALUES ('{:s}', '{:s}', '{:s}', '{:s}');""".format(table1,"""0""",string1,string2,string3)
```

but the same error is generated.

Also

```
query1 = """INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"""
data1 = ("""table1"""","""0""",string1,string2,string3)
cursor1.execute(query1,data1)
```

and

```
query1 = """INSERT INTO %s VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');"""
data1 = ("""table1"""","""0""",string1,string2,string3)
cursor1.execute(query1,data1)
```

generate the same error.

How to fix this? Maybe, once the strings have been returned by the function, is it possible to re-define them with triple quotes?

Comment: Pass the values as parameters to [`cursor.execute`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) instead of formatting them into your string.

Comment: @khelwood I edited the question with another attempt, if it is what you were saying. If it's not, can you please make a simple example?

Comment: http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you add parameters to a statement.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"

cursor.execute(sql, [string1, string2, string3])
```

See [`MySQLCursor.execute()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).

In this example you don't have to explicitly quote the values because you're not gluing them into your SQL. Also, this is safer, because if the string contains an end quote and them some malicious SQL, it will not be executed.

You can't add the table name as a parameter, so if that was in a variable you *would* have to glue that into your SQL:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%s, %s, %s);".format(table_name)
```