# how to iterate through geojson elements

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgis, geojson

i want to execute the code in this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/storing-geojson-featurecollection-to-postgresql-with-postgis/142479#142479
but when i run the app i receive the following error:

```
query="""
KeyError: ' "type"'
```

please let me know how to fix it.

**code**:

```
def exeGeoFromGeoJSONToWKT(self):        
    query="""
     WITH data AS (
        SELECT '{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
  { "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
    "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
    },
  { "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
        ]
      },
    "properties": {
      "prop0": "value0",
      "prop1": 0.0
      }
    },
  { "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
       "type": "Polygon",
       "coordinates": [
         [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
           [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
         ]
     },
     "properties": {
       "prop0": "value0",
       "prop1": {"this": "that"}
       }
     }
   ]}'::json AS featuresCollection)
        SELECT 
        LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
        FROM (
        SELECT 
            ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832) AS LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
           
        FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(featuresCollection->'features') AS feature 
                FROM data) AS f
    """
    print(query)        

    data = self.connection.query(query,[])
    # print(data)        
    return data
```

**attempts**:

```
 query="""
     WITH data AS (
        SELECT $${ "type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
  { "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
    "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
    }
   ]}$$::json AS featuresCollection)
        SELECT 
        LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
        FROM (
        SELECT 
            ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832) AS LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
           
        FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(featuresCollection->'features') AS feature 
                FROM data) AS f
    """
```

Answer (score 0):

From the database perspective the query works just fine, but the issue seems to be in the query building. Your query has a JSON document containing multiple `"` double quotes, so either you escape them (`\"`) or try to add the JSON to the query using parameters as described in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45343693/2275388).

**Unrelated**: You do not need these 3 nested subqueries. A single query would do:

```
WITH data AS (
   SELECT '{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
           ...
          ]}'::json AS mygeojson
)

SELECT 
 ST_Transform(
  ST_SetSRID(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(json_array_elements(
      mygeojson->'features')->>'geometry'),
   4326),
  25832) AS feature 
FROM data
```

Comment: please see the attempts section above. i tried it as you recommended but i am getting thre same results#

Comment: @LetsamrIt infrom the database perspective this query works. You're having problems in python when building the sql statement. Perhaps you should build your query using parameters (as I believe this json doc won't be hardcoded ;-)), e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44693970/2275388

Comment: is featuresCollection is the same as FeatureCollection??

Comment: @LetsamrIt it depends. `featuresCollection` is the alias you chose for the json document and it is case insensitive. `"FeatureCollection"` is the value of the `"type"` inside the json document and I believe it is case sensitive ;)

Comment: @LetsamrIt I edited my answer to make my point clearer. Mind the new alias for the json document/string.

Comment: hi, would you please answer this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68631428/geometry-is-not-recognized-a-parameter-to-st-find-srid